send file type MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
This is the script:
   var allegato = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdmnuQ35OmvI"

   var utente="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(allegato);

   var mimeType = file.getMimeType();
   Logger.log(mimeType);  

   GmailApp.sendEmail(utente, 'Attachment example', 'Allegato un file.', {
    name: 'Prova stampa',
     attachments:[file] });

This is the execution:
Execution log
11:33:28 Notification Execution started

11:33:29 Information application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

11:33:30 Notification Execution completed

The attachment arrives as a PDF
Question: How do I get it to arrive as a "google sheets" type?
Thanks for your help
I expect to receive a google sheets file and not a pdf

Google sheets file format is proprietory, not documented and therefore not shareable as a blob. You can only send a link to the Google sheets file.
